# Can I do the below problem with ML?

Tags: machine-learning, python

My dataset has 3 fields ColumnX, ColumnA, Column B as below.

### Column X, Column_A ,      Column_B

AA, 1     ,        KEYWORD1 KEYWORD2 KEYWORD3

AA, 2    ,         KEYWORD4 KEYWORD5 KEYWORD6

XX, 3 , KEYWORD3 KEYWORD7

XX, 4, KEYWORD6 KEYWORD8

YY, 5, KEYWORD9

I removed the stop words in Column_B and kept the keywords.

So here Can I train a model which can classify the data with Column_X and Column_B and given an input from user which matches any keyword in Column B , returns Column_A

Sample output:

user gives an input : KEYWORD9.

my output should show ColumnX: YY and ColumnA: 5

I know it can be done with basic python but I want to use ML here

Comment: Isn't this just a ... lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Try an LSTM Encoder-decoder model. The encoder takes Column_B as input and Decoder gives Column X, Column_A as output. Or create a two machine learning models one for each column prediction.

Answer (score 0):

- column A seems to be a unique index independent from the features in column B, I don't understand why you want to predict it? If it's really unique it's impossible to predict for any new instance.

The standard way is to split column B into as many columns as there are possible keywords, then the value for each instance is 1 if it has this keyword, 0 otherwise. From that you can train any supervised model, for instance decision trees or SVM, in order to predict column X.

If you really want to predict column A for some reason, you can do the same process with an independent model or try to learn it jointly with column X.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using search

Without any machine learning involved, you can solve it by searching for the user input in `Column_B`. Here is a solution using pandas ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)).

```
import pandas as pd
import io
raw_data = """Column X,Column_A,Column_B
AA, 1 , KEYWORD1 KEYWORD2 KEYWORD3
AA, 2 , KEYWORD4 KEYWORD5 KEYWORD6
XX, 3 , KEYWORD3 KEYWORD7
XX, 4, KEYWORD6 KEYWORD8
YY, 5, KEYWORD9"""

f = io.StringIO(raw_data)

data = pd.read_csv(f)

# The following will give you a DataFrame with rows having KEYWORD9 in Column_B.
data[data["Column_B"].str.contains("KEYWORD9")]
```

## Solution using machine learning

With machine learning, you should specify what you are trying to *predict*, and what are the *features* you can use for this task.

For example, you may want to use machine learning to denoise the user input into a valid input.

However, you should first consider simpler solutions. For input denoising, you can use fuzzy search to guess the user's input, even with some typos in the input. Fuzzy search is an approximate string matching technique which does not requires any machine learning and will be much, much faster.